# What's next for New Horizons?

Tags: nasa, new-horizons, kuiper-belt

Five years ago [What's after Pluto for New Horizons?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4597/12102) was asked, and the answer turned out to be at first 'something in the Kuiper belt if we can find a good candidate' and finally 2014 MU69.

But now what?

The Voyagers have been faithfully reporting back for 40+ years but there's not very much for them to do these days, both because there's not much of anything where they are and because as their RTG power ramps down things need to be  powered off permanently.

Is that now New Horizon's fate as well, or are there more KBO's flyby's possible, or something else for it to do at 40+ AU from the Sun?

Comment: I really hope the answer is "getting recovered by our first nuclear high-isp ship for materials analysis".

Comment: @ikrase or even for a quick refurbishing and redeployment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is being set up for use in a parallax experiment to obtain a 3D impression of two nearby stars in relation to other background stars via stereoscopic combination of the spaceship's telescope with terrestrial telescopes.

http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/News-Center/News-Article.php?page=20200129.

Seems like the two stars are Proxima Centauri and Wolf 359 (Resistance is futile :-)).

Comment: more in Astronomy SE: [Distance to Proxima Centauri (Gaia VS New Horizons parallax program)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34994/7982)